# Google API client bug, sending locations

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

I want to create that I send every few seconds a message to GCM. But after some time I want to remove the locationupdates again. For sending the data to the intentservice of gcm I use a pendingintent. Now every time and it happens a lot I get this error :

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.lt.removeLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.task_1.Location.LocationUpdate.stopLocationUpdates(LocationUpdate.java:83)
            at com.example.task_1.Location.LocationUpdate.onStartCommand(LocationUpdate.java:52)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2704)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
public class LocationUpdate extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DRIVER";
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private String driverId;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Intent mGcmIntentService;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        boolean stopService = false;
        if (intent != null)
            stopService = intent.getBooleanExtra("stopservice", false);
        if (stopService)
            stopLocationUpdates();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        pref = getSharedPreferences("driver_app", MODE_PRIVATE);
        driverId = pref.getString("driver_id", "");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        mGcmIntentService = new Intent(this,SendDataIntentService.class);
        mGcmIntentService.putExtra("ID", "FusedLocation");
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, mGcmIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mPendingIntent);
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mGcmIntentService = new Intent(this,SendDataIntentService.class);
        mGcmIntentService.putExtra("ID", "FusedLocation");
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, mGcmIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mPendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Anyone know how to solve this bug? Or how to fix it? I searched on the internet but can't find anything.

Comment: I'm on my phone now and so can't see line numbers. But at line 83 of your code the client isn't connected. Look into blocking until there's a connection (don't block the ui thread though)

Comment: Can you be more specific, how can I check till there is a connection? Implementing a while loop? Or can you hint me up with a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `stopLocationUpdates()` method, you are not waiting for the API to be connected before you call `removeLocationUpdates()`.

One simple way to fix this would be to set a boolean flag when you need to remove location callbacks, but the API is not connected.

Add a member variable:

```
private boolean isRemoving = false;
```

Then modify the logic so that it waits for the API to connect before unregistering for location callbacks.

In the `stopLocationUpdates()` method:

```
public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        isRemoving = true; //added
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    else {
        mGcmIntentService = new Intent(this, SendDataIntentService.class);
        mGcmIntentService.putExtra("ID", "FusedLocation");
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, mGcmIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mPendingIntent);
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

In the `onConnected()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    if (isRemoving){
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
    else {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

You would also want to set the flag back to false in `startLocationUpdates()`:

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    isRemoving = false; //added
    mGcmIntentService = new Intent(this,SendDataIntentService.class);
    mGcmIntentService.putExtra("ID", "FusedLocation");
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, mGcmIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mPendingIntent);
}
```

Also in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    isRemoving = false; //added
    pref = getSharedPreferences("driver_app", MODE_PRIVATE);
    driverId = pref.getString("driver_id", "");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Edit:  To re-start the location callbacks after they have been previously cancelled, you can use the `onStartCommand()` method.

Modify `onStartCommand()` so that it can both stop and start location updates:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    boolean stopService = false;
    if (intent != null) {
        stopService = intent.getBooleanExtra("stopservice", false);
    }

    if (stopService) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
    else{
        isRemoving = false;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Then, in order to re-start location updates, you would call `startService()` with an Intent that has `stopservice` set to false:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationUpdate.class);
    i.putExtra("stopservice", false);
    startService(i);
```

Comment: It still gives me some errors... I can't figure out why, but sometimes it works sometimes don't. I start and stop it when a user clicks a button on the UI.

Comment: When I call it for the first thim, the locations are send. Then I remove them and after that when I want to send back locations the oncreate and onconnected is not called anymore.

Comment: @TimDirks I just updated the answer, let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, do you know maybe aswell if I fill in a timeinterval of 900 000 (means sending data every 15 minutes) , but it sends the data every 4 minutes? Do I need to include something more specific?

Comment: @TimDirks Sure, no problem!  If I understand correctly, it sounds like you should use the `setFastestInterval()` method in your `LocationRequest`.  From the documentation: `If you don't call this method, a fastest interval will be selected for you. It will be a value faster than your active interval `    See documentation here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setFastestInterval(long)  example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you so much sir for clearing doubt. But I have one problem. After closing 1 service I am again starting 2 service but Its not starting. I followed all your steps. Yes GoogleClientApi not yet connected Crashed has been solved but How can I again start Service ?