# Can able to stop location update, Android service

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to create a route tracking app. it need to track location even if the app is in background. so i created a service and add code to this service. Following are my code. but there is one problem. I start the service from my main activity.

```
public void startTracking(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationIntentService.class));
}

public void stopTracking(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationIntentService.class));
}
```

It start the service and locations are inserted to a local db. But i cant stop these service. When i stop service using above code it still track the location. How can i stop location update.

```
public class LocationIntentService extends IntentService implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = LocationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;

    public LocationIntentService() {
        super("LocationIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, " ***** Service on handled");
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            createLocationRequest();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, " ***** Service on connected");
        startLocationUpdates();
        openDB();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, " ***** Service on suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Location changed");
        mLastLocation = location;

        String latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.e(TAG, " ##### Got new location"+ latitude+ longitude);

        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();
        String timestamp = today.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

        dbAdapter.insertRow(latitude, longitude, timestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Service is Destroying...");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        closeDB();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stoping...");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update starting...");
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    private void openDB() {
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.close();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        Log.e(TAG, " ***** Creating location request");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, " ***** Update google play service ");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i call the stopLocationUpdates() from my MainActivity. I think the service is stop after connecting to the mGoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it's not working for you is that you are using an `IntentService`, so calling `stopService()` will not cause `onDestroy()` to be called, presumably because it was already called after `onHandleIntent()` has completed.  There is no need to ever call `stopService()` on an `IntentService` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250745/proper-way-to-stop-intentservice/10250896#10250896).

It looks like you should probably just use `Service` instead of `IntentService`.  That way, when you call `stopService()`, it would call `onDestroy()` and unregister for location updates, as you expect.

The only other change you would need to make would be to override `onStartCommand()` instead of `onHandleIntent()`.

You would have your class extend `Service` instead of `IntentService`, and then move your code to register for location updates to `onStartCommand`:

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, " ***** Service on start command");
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            createLocationRequest();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

This way you can still call `startService()` and `stopService()`, and it should work as you are expecting.

Comment: thanks. yes i think the Service() class is a better solution. will try with Service()

Comment: I need to send the location stored in local db to server(after some time period or if network is available). can you please suggest some tutorial or a starting point?

Comment: @bolt123 For that you use `timerTask`

Comment: @Daniel Nugent there is one problem for using IntentService. When i stop using intent action "stoplocationupdates" the mGoogleApiClient is always null.Solution Option 2 - Stick with the IntentService is not working. any idea?

Comment: @bolt123  Is it still giving you location updates at that point?

Comment: @Daniel Nugent yes, it will give the location updates

Comment: @bolt123 I just realized that using solution 2, you will probably need to re-connect to the GoogleApiClient, I just updated the answer, and take a look at the solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562193/google-api-client-bug-sending-locations/30562317#30562317

Comment: @Daniel Nugent thnks, will check that. btw, now i stored the location in a db. i need to update the whole stored locations to server when stoping the service. which is the best practice. sending them all in a list? any suggestion

Comment: To prevent anybody from the 'GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.' -Bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne

Answer (score 1):

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Comment: how can i call the stopLocationUpdates() from my MainActivity. I think the service is stop after connecting to the mGoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 0):

call stopLocationUpdates() method in stopService()

Comment: how can i call the stopLocationUpdates() from my MainActivity. I think the service is stop after connecting to the mGoogleApiClient.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop your services. Then called this line in **LocationIntentService.class**.

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Comment: how can i call the stopLocationUpdates() from my MainActivity. I think the service is stop after connecting to the mGoogleApiClient.