# GetLastLocation always returns null

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, google-api-client

I try to access the last known location in a Fragment as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

in my onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

in my onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

The Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

and the on Connected **is called!!**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
    }
}
```

and the mLastLocation is always null. Everytime I try to call GetLastLocation() it returns null.

Any idea why?

Comment: `getLastLocation()` has a high tendency to return null.  It also does not request a new location, so even if you get a location, it could be very old, and not reflect the current location.  Better to register a listener, even if you just unregister after you get the first `onLocationChanged()` callback.  Take a look at the code in this answer, it's a very stripped down and basic implementation of registering a location listener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009

Answer (score 0):

I never tried that approach, I usually create a `LocationProvider` that implements `LocationsSource` and `LocationListener`. Here's an example that may help you with this approach:
[How to get My Location changed event with Google Maps android API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742551/how-to-get-my-location-changed-event-with-google-maps-android-api-v2)