# getLastLocation returns null when called from onActivityResult

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, activity-lifecycle

I'm using GooglePlayServices location API and it's working fine. (All required permissions have been granted to the app.)

Everywhere I execute this piece of code:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

I get the current location ... except for one case: When it's called from an `onActivityResult` hook, in this case it returns null.

Is this an expected behavior of the API? What am I missing?

## NOTE

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null) question. As I mentioned, this behavior only occurs when querying the location from an `onActivityResult` hook. Everything works like a charm everywhere else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583187/getlastlocation-always-returns-null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null

Comment: Keep checking for null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocationClient getLastLocation() return null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null)