# getLastLocation returns a null value

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I have followed this guide https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#permissions, and I'm not able to receive the last location.

I need the location just one time.

Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DAILY_FORECAST = "DAILY_FORECAST";
    public static final String HOURLY_FORECAST = "HOURLY_FORECAST";

    private Forecast mForecast;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;

    @Bind(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
    @Bind(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
    @Bind(R.id.summaryLabel) TextView mSummaryLabel;
    @Bind(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.refreshImageView) ImageView mRefreshImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //mLatitude = 37.8267;
        //mLongitude = -122.423;


        mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
            }
        });

        getForecast(mLatitude, mLongitude);
    }

    private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
        String apiKey = "48fb6c0ca3567d0b17bf99b400ef5606";
        String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
                "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            toggleRefresh();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void toggleRefresh() {
        if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();

        mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature() + "");
        mTimeLabel.setText("At " + current.getFormattedTime() + " it will be");
        mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() + "");
        mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChance() + "%");
        mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummary());

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(current.getIconId());
        mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        Forecast forecast = new Forecast();

        forecast.setCurrent(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
        forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
        forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

        return forecast;
    }

    private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
        JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

        Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Day day = new Day();

            day.setSummary(jsonDay.getString("summary"));
            day.setIcon(jsonDay.getString("icon"));
            day.setTime(jsonDay.getLong("time"));
            day.setTemperatureMax(jsonDay.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
            day.setTimezone(timezone);

            days[i] = day;
        }

        return days;
    }

    private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
        JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

        Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
            Hour hour = new Hour();

            hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
            hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getDouble("temperature"));
            hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));
            hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
            hour.setTimezone(timezone);

            hours[i] = hour;
        }

        return hours;
    }

    private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");

        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

        JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

        Current current = new Current();
        current.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
        current.setTime(currently.getInt("time"));
        current.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
        current.setTemperature(currently.getInt("temperature"));
        current.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
        current.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
        current.setTimeZone(timezone);

        Log.d(TAG, current.getFormattedTime());

        return current;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    @OnClick (R.id.dailyButton)
    public void startDailyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DAILY_FORECAST, mForecast.getDailyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.hourlyButton)
    public void startHourlyActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyForecastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(HOURLY_FORECAST, mForecast.getHourlyForecast());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

`

Comment: Where is the code for getting latitude and longitude??
can you share

Comment: 1- Make sure you are connected to Google Play Services

Comment: Because it can... Asked bazillion times...  Do some research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLastLocation()` has a high tendency to return null. It also does not request a new location, so even if you get a location, it could be very old, and not reflect the current location. Better to register a listener, even if you just unregister after you get the first onLocationChanged() callback.

This question gets asked a lot, and usually is marked as a duplicate of [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830047/locationclient-getlastlocation-return-null)

However, in your case, it also looks like you just forgot to call `connect()`:

```
 buildGoogleApiClient();
 mGoogleApiClient.connect(); //added
```

You can use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009) as a reference for registering for location callbacks, which is suggested if you want to get an accurate current location.

Edit:  Since you need only one location, here is a slightly modified version of that code, which requests location updates, and then un-registers for location updates after the first location comes in.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        //no need to do a null check here:
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        //remove location updates if you just need one location:
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "getLastLocation() has a high tendency to return null.": Under what circumstances this API returns null even if location setting is ON?

Comment: @SantoshSalunke Better explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32291415/4409409

Comment: Thanks Daniel. On my Nexus-5, I observed that getLastLocation returns null even after I launch Google Map app and then launch my app again. Even if location is detected correctly in Google Map app, getLastLocation API returns null. I did not understand: If Google Map had requested for location then why cached location was not updated.