# Unable to get current location in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Greetings of the day. I'm working on app in which i need to show a map.
I want a map to be shown by default at my current location but i'm not able to do so. I've tried several ways to get Current Location (LatLng).
I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290045/error-invoke-virtual-method-double-android-location-location-getlatitude-on) too, the link works fine on emulator when i send LatLng from Android Device Monitor but fails on real device.

and wrote a simple piece of code given below

```
 Location myLoc=mMap.getMyLocation();
    double cLat=myLoc.getLatitude();
    double cLng=myLoc.getLongitude();
    showMap(cLat,cLng);
```

the above code returns NULL. Got stucked . Please help

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the case where the Location is null, and fallback to a sensible default, like centering the map on a major city. Google's documentation states that the Location [can be null in rare cases](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). In practice I have found this happens most often when the device has been indoors for a long time, or has had location services disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        CheckGPS();

        ImageView textView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.center);
        Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash);
        textView.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);


    }

    private void setUpLocation() {
        // First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     */
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            getCities(latitude, longitude);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }
            }, 4000);


        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }
            }, 4000);
        }
    }

    private void getCities(double lat, double lng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            //String locality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            API.OnCityID(SplashScreen.this, cityName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void CheckGPS() {
        // Get Location Manager and check for GPS & Network location services
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            // Build the alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
            builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    }, 1500);

                }
            });
            Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
            setUpLocation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Android studio then make you need to add dependencies of Google play services