# Android GPS get location return null in x86 emulator but return truth in arm emulator

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gps, android-emulator, locationmanager

I try to get LastKnowLocation using LocationManager,here is my code:

```
LocationManager mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (mLocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Location mLocation = mLocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

I already add permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then I use DDMS to send latitude and longitude to emulator,but when I use x86 CPU emulator I get error like

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
```

When I use arm CPU emulator I get the right latitude and longitude.Anyone who can tell why I can't get right location in x86 emulator,and how can I deal with it.Thanks.

Comment: see before trying to extract the latitude and longitude.. be sure location is not null and also when using double and parsing the lat long ; make sure the location is not null and dont using GPS provider ; most of the time the location will be null... so instead use NETWORK_PROVIDER...but make sure the GPS is turned ON but including a check on GPS stat

Answer (score 0):

Solved! the getLastKnownLocation() method doesn't request new location,it just can check if if there was a last known location from some other app's location request.When I used arm emulator I had used other app to get location,so my code could also get the location.

So if your app return error likes

`invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference`

it may due to the getLastKnownLocation() method,try to use requestLocationUpdates() to get location.

Look this:
[[Error invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290045/error-invoke-virtual-method-double-android-location-location-getlatitude-on][1])