# Google Maps API get current location

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, currentlocation

I am trying to do the simple task of getting the current location of my device, however after some mind bending hours, I still can't seem to get it to work..

My MapFragment code:

```
package com.example.curroorbis_v0;



import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private int TotalMarkers = 1;

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Add a marker in Denmark and move the camera + zoom
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 0);
            return;
        }
                    // THIS MAKES IT WORK!!
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 , 0, this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        LatLng denmark = new LatLng(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude(), locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(denmark).title("Marker at You"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(denmark));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(denmark, 15));

        // Add custom markers
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions waypoint = new MarkerOptions();
                waypoint.position(latLng);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                waypoint.title("Waypoint " + TotalMarkers);
                mMap.addMarker(waypoint);

                //Logs lat/lng for each waypoint
                Log.i("Waypoint", String.valueOf(waypoint.getPosition()));

                TotalMarkers++;
            }
        });


    }






    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("Message: ","Location changed, " + location.getAccuracy() + " , " + location.getLatitude()+ "," + location.getLongitude());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

When I run this code on my samsung galaxy s8, I get the fatal error:

```
2020-06-16 21:42:00.247 31624-31624/com.example.curroorbis_v0 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.curroorbis_v0, PID: 31624
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.curroorbis_v0.MapFragment.onMapReady(MapFragment.java:86)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
        at cx.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817051@20.18.17 (040408-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817051@20.18.17 (040408-0):2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

And the app terminates.

To anyone who doesn't bother finding line 86, it is this piece of code:

```
LatLng denmark = new LatLng(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude(), locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude());
```

If anyone has a clue to what might be going on, please don't hesitate.

Comment: Can you add some more lines from the stacktrace?

Comment: @EightBitBoy sure can, It should be updated now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290045/error-invoke-virtual-method-double-android-location-location-getlatitude-on)

Comment: @RafaelW. tried to implement the fix, but seem to have problems with:
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 0, this);