# Android: FusedLocationProviderApi: LocationRequest vs Device location mode

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using new Location API ([FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)) and get confuse about it.

I intend to use LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. But, on device, if user choose the location mode is save battery (network only). -> What is the bahevior for my app?

- Does it update with hight accuracy (with internet, gps..) OR
- Does it will be limited follow the setting of user?

Please correct me if i missunderstand anything.

Comment: The permission you set in the AndroidManifest.xml has more of an effect than anything you set in the code.  If you have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the manifest, you can still get very accurate results from just Network Location.  Take a look at this answer exploring the functionality of different settings, all tests done with the device set to Battery Saving for Location Mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009